# Uniform Continuity Proofs (bounded sequence)

Tags: limits, uniform-continuity

Let a $\in R$, $f:(a,+\infty)$ -> R be a continuous function, and assume that the limit of f(x) as n goes to $+\infty$ exists. Show that f is uniformly continuous. Is the converse true?

I'm stuck on the second question. I was able to prove the first part, but am unsure mainly whether I should be looking for a counterexample or to prove a contradiction.

Comment: What if $f(x) = x$?

Comment: You'd want a function that is uniformly continuous but whose limit doesn't exist as n goes to infinity right? X is uniformly continuous, but the limit as n approaches infinity equals infinity, which is a number that doesn't exist. Would this work as a formal counterexample?

Comment: Otherwise a function like $f(x) = \sin x$ is uniformly continuous but the limit as $x\to +\infty$ does not exist (in any sense).

Comment: Ok yeah, I think sin(x) is a better counterexample because the limit itself DNE while the limit for x can technically be infinity.